# Group total number of records based on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, group-by

In my `SqlServer 2008`, I have a table named Table1, with one column named `IncDate` which is a DateTime.

I need to run a query which returns the total of records by that date. For example, my table has these records:

```
IncDate
09/09/2012 16:21:51.547
09/09/2012 16:22:11.032
10/09/2012 13:51:33.327
```

My query needs to output:

```
Date................Total
09/09/2012...........2 
10/09/2012...........1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `CAST()` the date as date-only.

```
SELECT Cast(incdate as date) DateOnly, Count(*) AS Total
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Cast(incdate as date)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd075/2)

If you do not `CAST()` the date to date-only, then the counts will be off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
select cast(incdate as date) as date, count(*)
from table1
group by cast(incdate as date)
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT cast(incdate as [date]) as [idate], count(incdate) totalCount
FROM table1
GROUP BY cast(incdate as [date])
ORDER BY totalCount
```